# Newline character before numbers

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am cleaning a text file and writing a regex to suit my needs. However, an error is creeping which I cannot understand.

Example text:

```
In the spring of 2014
```

Intended Result:

```
In,the,spring,of,2014
```

But my output throws:

```
In,the,spring,of,
2014
```

I don't understand why 2014 goes to the newline when I am removing all \n,\r,\t from the file. This is happening to all numbers in my text block. Any word will help.

Edit: Regex I am using

```
    newline = re.sub("[/ --(),.\n\r\t\\\\]+",",",line)
```

Solution: The error was due to the text editor. I was using TextEdit on Mac, no idea why was it showing a newline feed. Vim and emacs showed a clean file.

Comment: Since I'm unaware of any general bugs or features to this effect, try to provide a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: are you using any `print` statements?

Comment: Not using any print. Writing the output to a text file

Comment: It's a naive regex... but I still don't think it should have any conflict for numbers... maybe it's a special character I am missing to replace

Comment: @Divi
 
Your regex seems to work fine:

`import re; re.sub("[/ --(),.\n\r\t\\\\]+", ",", "In the spring of 2014")` > 'In,the,spring,of,2014'.

Try to capture and log the string right after the replace (e.g. with a print statement) before processing it further, e.g. writing to file.

Check the charset of the file, maybe print each char's hex value to see what's between «of» and «2014»?

Comment: I tried your regex and it works for me, too.  If you could post more of your code (including the code that writes your output), that'd be helpful.

Comment: Also, here's a stupid question: have you verified that your input doesn't contain newlines before each number?  ('Cause that'd explain what you're observing.)

Comment: I also couldn't replicate your problem. Try troubleshooting outside that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('\s+')
>>> re.sub(pattern, ',', text)
'In,the,spring,of,2014'
>>>
```

or

```
>>> ','.join(text.split(' '))
'In,the,spring,of,2014'
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not remove the problem. I am not using \s as it is not working for special characters like '--' in my file. The numbers are still getting pushed to a newline even if I ignore this fact.

Comment: please post a sample file

Comment: It is still giving me newline feeds in between the text. I don't understand how there would be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have a **non-breaking space** there `\xA0` (`\x20` is usual space).

**Regex pattern:** `[/\x20\xA0--(),.\n\r\t\\\\]+`